# How to compute delta time, for unequal data sets?

Tags: python

I require to compute the delta_time between two data sets: The first data set, has formate like y:mm:d:h:m:s and the second data set has h:m:s only (y:m:d is the same as with the first data set)
I attempted with the following script, but it did not work.

Script for the first dataset:

```
names = ["year","month","day","hour","minute","second", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]
ev = pd.read_csv('event.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
ev_time= ev[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']]
t_a=pd.to_datetime(ev_time)
```

script for the second data set:

```
names=["p1", "p2", "hour", "minute", "second"]
arr = pd.read_csv('arrival.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
arr_time=arr[['hour', 'minute', 'second']]
 t_b=pd.to_datetime(arr_time)
```

To compute the difference in seconds:

```
tt=t_a-t_b
a=tt.dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer because it is becoming too messy. I created some reproducible code. There are shorter way to do this but I think this approach is more versatile.

```
names = ["year","month","day","hour","minute","second", 'd1']
departure = pd.DataFrame(columns=names, data=[[2021, 7, 1, 17, 0, 0, 99]])
departure['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(departure[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']])
departure_datetime = departure.iloc[0, -1]

names = ["hour","minute","second"]
arrival = pd.DataFrame(columns=names, data=[[18, 0, 0], [19, 0, 0]])
arrival['datetime'] = arrival.apply(lambda row: dt.datetime(departure_datetime.year,departure_datetime.month, departure_datetime.day, row['hour'], row['minute'], row['second']), axis=1)
arrival['duration'] = (arrival['datetime'] - departure_datetime).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: I am trying to use your sample code for my problem but still, there is an error about "dt". Even, in its original form, there is still an error. May you please recheck your code. Additionally, I find out another way to solve this problem, but not too efficient (I add my script as a reference, maybe you can modify it in an efficient way

Comment: This took my some time to figure out. If you use df['col_name'] you need to use df['col_name'].dt.year or something like that. You tell Pandas to use the datetime library for this issue. If instead it is just a normal datetime value like in my code departure_datetime, you don't need the .dt because python knows to use the datetime methods.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit of code works? Great, did not know that was even possible :) You want both data sets to have a datetime format. If you don't supply the date fields, you get a time field which does not compute nicely with datetime.

```
arr_time = pd.concat([ev_time[['year', 'month', 'day']], arr[['hour', 'minute', 'second']], axis=1)
t_b = pd.to_datetime(arr_time)
```

So first you join the date fields from one txt file and then the time from the other.

**Edit:**

Aah that is very useful information! Kind of hard without an example to test it on. In that case you can do something like this:

```
a = (t_a[0] - t_b).dt.total_seconds()
```

or if you don't want to soft code it:

```
a = (dt.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 18, 0) - t_b).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: yes, first part works well, there is a problem in the second part

Comment: Did you try by also providing the date fields to the second part? Otherwise you get a time field instead of datetime

Comment: Even, I have tried your approach earlier but it did not works

Comment: Would you mind sharing what does not work?

Comment: Because, in the first dataset, we have only one row and 6 columns (Y, M, D, H, M, S) whereas in second dataset we have more than 100 rows and 3 columns (H, M, S). So, when we concatenate the two datasets, it only works for the first row.

Comment: Still, there is a problem in the concatenation step, it only concatenates the first row of the second dataset. That, why i get the time-delat for the first element only.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: data set1

```
names = ["year","month","day","hour","minute","second", "lat", "long", "depth", "Mag"]
ev = pd.read_csv('event.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
t1= ev[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']]
ev_time = pd.to_datetime(t1)
```

Step 2: Dataset 2 (here, we need to calculate the dimensions of dataset2)

```
names=["station", "phase", "hour", "minute", "second"]
arr = pd.read_csv('arrival.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
array2= arr[['hour', 'minute', 'second']]
#dim=len(array2)
array2 = pd.DataFrame(array2)
```

Step 3: Dimension equalization

```
array1=ev[['year', 'month', 'day']]
array1 = np.tile(array1, (26, 1))
array1 = pd.DataFrame(array1)
array1.columns =['Year', 'month', 'day']
```

Step 4: Concatenation

```
arr_time = pd.concat([array1, array2], axis=1)
arr_time = pd.to_datetime(arr_time)
```

Step 4: Time delay in seconds

```
a = (arr_time-ev_time[0]).dt.total_seconds()
print(a)
```